# Explanation on how this works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I have a pretty basic understanding of inheritance and so when using it there are a few moments like this where I find it difficult to understand what's fully happening and it probably doesn't help that I'm most likely not using it properly.

Anyways though I have these 3 classes

```
public abstract class EffectBase
{
    public enum EffectType
    {
        harm,
        help,
        self
    }

    public EffectType type;
    public float duration;

    public void Activate()
    {
        Debug.Log("Activating effect");
        ApplyEffect();
    }

    public abstract void ApplyEffect();
    public abstract void End();
}
```

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<EffectBase> effects = new List<EffectBase>();

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Q pressed");
            AddEffect(new SpeedEffect());
        }
    }

    public void AddEffect(EffectBase effect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Adding effect");
        effects.Add(effect);
        effect.Activate();
    }
}
```

```
public class SpeedEffect : EffectBase
{
    public override void ApplyEffect()
    {
        Debug.Log("Speed effect applied");
    }

    public override void End()
    {
        Debug.Log("Speed effect ended");
    }
}
```

When I call the AddEffect method I pass a new instance of SpeedEffect (I think it's an instance) as the parameter and then in the AddEffect method I call the Activate method from it, however, in the SpeedEffect class, it doesn't have or override that method so I'm assuming it goes to the base class which does have it and continues and now here's where I get confused in the Activate method it calls the ApplyEffect method, but how does it know to call the one in the SpeedEffect class?

Comment: Because it's abstract and an abstract method has to be overridden in a derived class. So when the "ApplyEffect" function is called, it uses the created instances overridden method, in this instance "SpeedEffect"

Comment: *how does it know to call the one in the SpeedEffect class?* - as opposed to.. which other one?

Answer (score 0):

Despite not having an override for `Activate()` that method still exists in the `SpeedEffect` class, you just didn't need to write any code for it since its the same code so theres no need to duplicate it.

The code for `Activate()` calls the `ApplyEffect()` method for whatever class its being called from. In this case: `EffectBase.Activate()` and `SpeedEffect.Activate()` have the same code in terms of reading it, but they are not the same; `EffectBase.ApplyEffect()` and `SpeedEffect.ApplyEffect()` are two different methods and each are called from their respective classes.